# Why was karma important?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I just finished Black Ops 2 and it left me wondering why Karma was so important. Why would anyone be after her in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

> She developed the Celerium device. Menendez wants to kill her to tie up loose ends.

A lengthy [breakdown of the plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_II#Plot) can be found on Wikipedia.